# Where should I populate my dropdownlist so that it retains its selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have seen posts which recommend that I populate the list within a if(!IsPostback) block.

However, I only generate the dropdown lists in response to postbacks so I dont think that will work for me.

What I currently do is databind the dropdownlists in `Page_Init`.  However, when I inspect the list after a new selection is made (and therefore the autopostback has been triggered) using "inspect element" I see that the first item in the list is always "selected."

Please let me know how to keep the selection selected through a postback.

Answer (score 1):

If you bind the control in Page_Init, then you'll lose your selection. Don't do that.

Bind the control once, then ViewState will retain the control data. But when the selection changes, that will be sent to the server, and the `SelectedIndexChanged` event will fire.

---

More generally, any properties you set on a control before the `Render` phase will be saved in ViewState. On the next Post Back, the control will load the contents of ViewState, and therefore will restore itself to the state it was in before the PostBack.

The control will then take note of any POSTed values that were sent on the PostBack. This includes changes in the selection, textbox contents, etc. The control will fire the appropriate *something*Changed event to indicate that there has been a change from the prior state of ViewState.